# Optimize prime number finder and cpu speed checker in R

Tags: r, time, primes

I have following code to find prime numbers in 10 seconds:

```
prime_nums = function (){
    ptm <- proc.time()

    p_nums = c(2)
    counter = 2
    while (TRUE){
        isPRIME = FALSE
        counter = counter +1
        for(n in p_nums) {
            if(n > sqrt(counter)){ isPRIME=TRUE; break; }
            if(counter %% n == 0){ isPRIME = FALSE; break;}
        }
        if(isPRIME) { p_nums[length(p_nums)+1]=counter ; cat("",counter,";")}
        if((proc.time()[3]-ptm[3]) > 10) break; 
    }
}
```

However, this is written with many loops which are generally not preferred in R. How can I optimize this code to become as fast as possible?

---

EDIT: 
I found following code to be fastest:

```
prime_nums_fastest = function (){
    ptm <- proc.time()

    p_nums = c(2L,3L,5L,7L)
    counter = 7L

    while (TRUE){
        isPRIME = FALSE
        counter = counter +2L       
        loc = 4*sqrt(counter)/log(counter,2)   

        isPRIME = !any(0 == (counter %% p_nums[1:loc]))

        if(isPRIME) { p_nums[length(p_nums)+1]=counter }
        if((proc.time()[3]-ptm[3]) > 10) break;
    }
    print(p_nums)
}
```

Initial small primes are kept to simplify. Using 2*sqrt.. or even 3*sqrt... for loc parameter leads to inclusion of non-primes. Significantly less primes need to be checked than using 1:sqrt(counter).

Comment: A loop is not preferred over vectorized code, but that doesn't mean that you should never use a loop.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  Do you want to find more primes in 10 seconds on a given CPU?

Comment: Yes. Currently, I am reaching till number 220973. I want to make it faster so that I get to larger numbers in 10 seconds.

Comment: WP says, "Like other similar languages such as APL and MATLAB, R supports matrix arithmetic." I don't know R (or APL) but see if you can encode in it an equivalent of [APL's `(~R∊R∘.×R)/R←1↓ιR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29#Examples) -- `reduce set_diff (reducing element-wise-sum (repeat 10_times [2..100]))` for a kind-of sieve of Eratosthenes (here, up to 100), which might be faster than the trial division testing, esp. as it works on array as a whole at each step. -- or try this: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#R

Comment: Thanks for the information and the link. On the rosettacode also, sqrt(n) is being used. We want to stop at prime upto sqrt(n) not sqrt(n)TH prime. Using n/log(n); pi(sqrt(n)) is closer as discussed on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473055/relation-between-a-number-and-position-of-smallest-prime-larger-than-its-square/24473296

Comment: right now you have a trial division algorithm (yes?); sieve of Eratosthenes usually is much much faster.

Comment: Can you modify sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm to find maximum prime numbers in T seconds (eg 10 seconds) (rather than n number of primes)?

Comment: you can work by short segments for that. Make the length of the segment a parameter and adjust for best performance empirically.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `cat` command.  That's expensive.  With it in place, I get to 384239.  Returning the vector of primes instead gets me to 471617, a significant improvement.

Changing `n > sqrt(counter)` to `n*n > counter` gets me to 477163, a small improvement.

Changing `p_nums` and `counter` to be of type `integer` gets me to 514859, another small improvement.  This is achieved by modifying the lines where these are defined and adjusted:

```
p_nums = c(2L)
counter = 2L
# ... and inside the loop:
  counter = counter +1L
```

Note that you can vectorize the loop which determines that a value is prime, with code such as this:

```
isPRIME = !any(0 == (counter %% p_nums[1:sqrt(counter)]))
```

Using that instead of `for` gets me to 451249, a significant regression (using no `cat` and using integer arithmetic).  This is because R does not have lazy list evaluation, so the modulus is taken for every value, then they are tested against 0.  This is an advantage of `for` in this case.

Comment: Using if(n*n > counter){ isPRIME=TRUE; break; } I am reaching 218117 which is less than my code.

Comment: My code has for(n in p_nums) so it checks division by only prime numbers stored in p_nums.

Comment: How can I make "p_nums and counter to be of type integer"?

Comment: If p_nums is (2,3,5,7,11,13), p_nums[1:sqrt(25)] will not stop at 5 (3rd value) but at 11 (5TH VALUE rather than value 5), hence the regression that you are getting.

Comment: @rnso Good point.  But it's quite difficult to stop the computation at the correct point.

Comment: Possibly findInterval or binsearch (of gtools package) can be used.