# Relation between a number and position of smallest prime larger than its square root in the list of primes

Tags: r, algorithm, math, primes

While making a list of prime numbers, one needs to check if a number is divisible by any prime equal to or smaller than its square root. However, instead of checking every time whether a prime number is more than square root of number being checked (as done on this page: [Optimize prime number finder and cpu speed checker in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467936/optimize-prime-number-finder-and-cpu-speed-checker-in-r/24468241#comment37872163_24468241) ), it will be useful if one can know its position in the list. Is there any relation or equation between a number and the position of smallest prime larger than its square root in a list of prime numbers. Following code (in R) and graph shows that there may be a relation:

```
pnum_sqrtpos_plot = function(){
    p_nums = c(2L,3L)
    counter = 3L
    sqrtcounter=1L
    sqrtposlist = c(1L,1L)
    countchecker=10000
    while (counter<200000){
        isPRIME = FALSE
        counter = counter +2L
        sqrtcounter = sqrt(counter)
        for(n in p_nums) {
            if(n > sqrtcounter){ isPRIME=TRUE; break; }
            if(counter %% n == 0){ isPRIME = FALSE; break;}
        }
        if(isPRIME) { p_nums[length(p_nums)+1]=counter 
            sqrtpos = which(p_nums>sqrt(counter))[1]
            sqrtposlist[length(sqrtposlist)+1] = sqrtpos
        }
        if(counter > countchecker) {cat("Numbers checked: ",counter,"\n");
                counterchecker = countchecker+10000;
        }
    }
    plot(p_nums, sqrtposlist
    , main="Relation between number & \nposition of smallest prime larger than its square root in list of primes"
    , xlab="Number", ylab="Position in list of prime numbers")
}
```

[image]
What could be the relation / equation? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The prime number theorem would be a good place to start.  There are roughly n / log(n) primes less than n.  Try asking the math stackexchange.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics rather than programming.

Comment: pi(n) ~= n/log(n); pi(sqrt(n)) ~= 2*sqrt(n)/log(n) is an approximation.

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, some non-primes are being included if I keep this criteria. Even with 3*sqrt... some non-primes are included. However, 4*sqrt... seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

In the example code you point to, you are building up a list of prime numbers in ascending order and at each point you check a number for primality by testing divisibility by each number in the list up to the square root of the number being tested.

If you have a list of numbers in ascending order of length n you can search this list to find the largest number smaller than sqrt(target) in time logarithmic in the length of the list using binary chop, which is faster than searching through the list one at a time.

In fact you can do better than this because you are looking for new primes in ascending order. If you remember the position of the largest number smaller than sqrt(target) for the previous number, you can search forward from here when dealing with the next number - so for each number you usually only have to check that you don't need to change the largest test divisor to check, and a small proportion of the time you have to move it by one position.

(These are all interesting little tweaks, but I doubt if they will speed up your code by any noticeable amount. I note that there is a profiler at http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rprof.html which you can use to see where your R program is spending its time. When optimising code it is usually worth while running such profilers, because humans are very bad at guessing what is expensive and what is not, and there is no point doubling the speed of code that is only consuming 1% of the total time).

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to incorporate all your suggestions.

Comment: and you don't even need to check whether you have to advance it by one notch or not - at all. you know it in advance too - when you turn the code inside out and instead, produce primes between the successive squares of primes (the supply of the smaller primes you can get by recursively using the same algorithm, knowing the first few primes are 2,3,...). If you read Haskell, [see this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Segmented_Generate_and_Test).

Comment: Thanks for this information and link.

Comment: @mcdowella: I have tried but I do not think your statement is correct: "remember the position of the largest number smaller than sqrt(target) for the previous number, you can search forward from here when dealing with the next number". Can you provide some code for this?

Comment: What I am saying is that the numbers you check for being prime increase. So if, for instance, you check 9 for being prime and find that you need to check divisors up to 3 then when you check 10 for being prime you need to check divisors up to at least 3, and notice that 4 is still too big to have to check. In fact until you come to check 16 the largest number you will need to check is 3. When you come to check 16 you will at last need to advance the largest divisor you need to check from 3 to 4.

Comment: OK. I get it now. So this will remove 'if(n > sqrtcounter)' statement from 'for' loop but I will have to add other statements for new logic before the 'for' loop.